# Problem with building and using Scintilla.NET

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-2.0

I'm using/building [Scintilla.NET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) and switched the project to .NET 2.0 for compatibility issues.

It works, but when I click the new tab button I get an error which says:

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

The problem occurs in this code:

```
ScintillaNet.Scintilla currentScin;
Stream Stream1;

public List <ScintillaNet.Scintilla> ScinList;

//Code for various events

private void New_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TabPage tabp = new TabPage();
    ScintillaNet.Scintilla scin = new ScintillaNet.Scintilla();
    scin.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    scin.Margins[0].Width = 20;
    scin.ConfigurationManager.CustomLocation = "My Styles";
    scin.ConfigurationManager.Language = "lua";

    scin.Parent = tabp;

    // This line throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
    ScinList.Add(scin);

    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabp);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have not initialized `ScinList`.  Fields of a class are initialized to their default value, which in this case is `null`.

You need to initialize it somewhere, either where it is declared...

```
public List<ScintillaNet.Scintilla> ScinList = new List<ScintillaNet.Scintilla>();
```

... or in the constructor ...

```
public CLASSNAMEHERE()
{
    ScinList = new List<ScintillaNet.Scintilla>();
}
```

If this line actually does appear in your code, please edit your question with the code that does so.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're not initializing `ScinList`.

Change this:

```
public List<ScintillaNet.Scintilla> ScinList;
```

To this:

```
public List<ScintillaNet.Scintilla> ScinList = new List<ScintillaNet.Scintilla>();
```

Comment: I didn't realise you had to initialise lists.. I can't think why I didn't though. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you define your public field ScinList:

```
public List <ScintillaNet.Scintilla> ScinList;
```

but you never actually create a new list and assign it to your field:

```
public List <ScintillaNet.Scintilla> ScinList = new List<ScintillaNet.Scintilla>();
```